# onClick not firing, event IS a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-md

I realize there are 400 questions with the same title here, but for every one, the issue is that the onClick method was NOT a function. Mine is.

```
<button
    type="button"
    key={level}
    onClick={() => {
      console.log("Why Can't You See Me?")
      props.onSelected(item)
    }}
  >
    {title()}
  </button>
```

I selected the button that I am clicking with chrome developer tools to show that it is 100% the correct button. I'm so confused as to why the onClick isn't firing.

[image]
[image]

The button is positioned "absolute", if that helps. Could there be anything intercepting the onClick event? I'm relatively new to frontend, but I'm assuming that the issue is with something over top of it, but i dont see it at all.

I'm using https://github.com/mlaursen/react-dd-menu, I basically copied their example code. Any thoughts?

Edit: Added a video demonstrating this: https://youtu.be/qnsp4XTAKzI ... something else it taking priority perhaps?

Edit 2: Here is a picture demonstrating the result of jsejcksn's command.. undefined:
[image]

Edit 3: Replaced {title()} with {"This button does not work"} and it still does not accept clicks.

Edit 4: Reproduced on Codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wozniak-r6vct?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: When you click the button, does it look like it clicks on the page? Is the cursor a pointer? Does the button styling change in some way? Can you post your CSS classes `dropdown-sub-button test-stack-overflow` up here?

Comment: It doesn't really look like it clicks on the page. The cursor turns into a hand. The button styling changes on hover. The two classes are actually empty, I can go ahead and remove them from the post.

Comment: Throw this into your code or console: `const body = document.querySelector('body')`, then `body.addEventListener('click', e => {console.log(e.target)} )`.  This will log the element you are clicking on.  That should show you if there's some hidden div overlaying your button and interfering.

Comment: @SethLutske when I click other buttons on the page, it logs them. When I click the button in question, nothing is logged. Does this mean that something is on top of it?

Comment: It seems likely, especially if your `onClick` function is identical.  I've gotten caught tearing my hair out over why something wasn't responding to mouse events, only to find there was an invisible div over the top of it.  This can happen, especially when `position: absolute` is involved.  Did you try my code?  That will tell you what the browser thinks you're clicking on.

Comment: Try this: Find the element in inspector > Elements tab. Right-click > Copy > Copy JS path. Then `const jsPath = document.querySelector("..."); jsPath.click();` This should definitely call your function.

Comment: @SethLutske yes, tried your code. All of the other button pushes triggered console logging, but this one didn't. There must be something on top of it. It's completely blank when I click that particular element.

Comment: That's very strange.  As long as your button is within the `<body>` tags, it should log *something* to the console.  With my code, even if something is over the top of it, you'd get that element logged in the console.  You don't happen to have a `pointer-events: none` in your css, do you?

Comment: There is no pointer-events CSS

Comment: @jsejcksn i added a screenshot. The result is undefined...

Comment: Why is the content of the button a function?  `{title()}`?  Is that intentional?  Shouldn't it be `{title}`?  Not sure if that's related...usually React throws an error that it cannot render an element whose children are a function.

Comment: I am creating a nested dropdown box using https://github.com/mlaursen/react-dd-menu. If the prop passed to this component indicates that there should be nested children beneath, then I change what I return inside of the button. But it doesnt seem to matter. If I replace it with "This button does not work", the same issue remains.

Comment: Can you please recreate the issue in a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/new. This will make it easier to debug.

Comment: @MattCarlotta What an amazing tool! Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wozniak-r6vct?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It looks like what's happening here is the `<DropDownMenu>` component may be removing your click handlers? https://github.com/mlaursen/react-dd-menu/blob/master/dist/DropdownMenu.js#L117 or at least front-running the click event.  Maybe try creating a forked variant of dd-menu that ignores clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from this line: https://github.com/mlaursen/react-dd-menu/blob/master/src/js/NestedDropdownMenu.js#L45. It's intercepting all clicks and stopping propagation. Removing this line: https://github.com/mlaursen/react-dd-menu/blob/master/src/js/NestedDropdownMenu.js#L54, fixes the issue.

**Working example**:

[image: Edit festive-varahamihira-cqxym]

---

That said, the `react-dd-menu` package is extremely dated. I'd recommend looking for other alternatives (or developing your own drop menu!).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! That's absolutely it. What you did there - you copy/pasted the file into your local directory, referenced that, made a small change but still referenced the root package.... I haven't seen that before, that's really cool . Adding that to my toolbelt for sure!

Comment: For people just coming here, the npm package I am using was calling ```    e.stopPropagation()``` which killed me. So this was the core issue.

Comment: In this case, it's easier to hack, but not always recommended if the package is in active development. On that note, I absolutely love codesandbox. The creators/contributors made an excellent rapid dev tool that I highly recommend to anyone who's looking for shareable code prototyping.